# Fetch data output [object%20Object] in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem fetching data.
when i console appears =
GET https://xxxxxx/core/smart-survey/v1/news/[object%20Object] 404

my code is like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is that, do you think? and what is the solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: `id` is an object. You're passing an object to `getNews`, so that shouldn't be particularly surprising. It's not clear what URL you _expected_ to make a request to - did you want search/query parameters, perhaps? And please post the [mre] **as text** when asking a question.

Comment: I want to show "Title", "Date", and "Content" data based on the loaded id. for example I open a url like this
http://localhost:9999/en/detail-article/6294e4e1f2d0f5003a3e70f7
then id 6294e4e1f2d0f5003a3e70f7 will load data "Title", "Date", and "Content" based on id 6294e4e1f2d0f5003a3e70f7. like that.

Comment: If you wanted to put `"6294e4e1f2d0f5003a3e70f7"` in the URL, why are you passing `{ row: 10, page: 1 }`? Also note there's absolutely no need to wrap  `axios.get` in `new Promise` - it _already returns a promise_ (which you know, because you call `.then`/`.catch` on it).

Comment: what should it be like? please give an example of the code. I modified like this { row: 10, page: 1, id: _id } but there is an error message

Comment: Well think it through - what do you want the value of `id` to be, and therefore _given the parameter is the id_ what should you pass when you call the function?!

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

you are passing object `{ row: 10, page: 1 }` to `getNews`  instead of `id`, so result url will `${your-url}/[object Object]`

Comment: what is the best solution like?